# Conditional Probability vs Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability

Problem with 2 questions: 
Suppose you are dealt 3 cards, standard deck. 
1. What is the probability you are dealt 3 Kings, given that the first two cards you were deal are kings.
2. Find the probability that you are dealt 3 Kings, given you were dealt at least 2 Kings.

The answer to 1st part is calculated using conditional probability formula, whereas answer to 2nd part uses Bayes' Theorem.

Could someone please explain the difference in calculations and wording of these questions. I feel like an intuitive explanation is slipping away and I have reached mental block. 
So, if I were to take a test and saw something like this on the test, how would I know that I need to use conditional probability for the 1st and Bayes' Theorem for 2nd?

Comment: The difference between the wording of the problems?  "*Given that the first two cards you were dealt are kings*" includes only the possibilities `KKn`, and `KKK` where `n` represents any non-king.  "*given you were dealt at least 2 kings*" includes only the possibilities `KKn`, `KnK`, `nKK`, and `KKK`.

Comment: Both parts should be able to be approached using the standard conditional probability formula... (*and really, Bayes' theorem is only one algebraic manipulation past the standard definition anyways...*).  Recall that $Pr(A\mid B)=\dfrac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$.  You should be able to calculate each of the following:   The probability all three cards are kings, the probability the first two cards are kings, the probability at least two of the cards are kings.  They should all be routine applications of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: Could you show how the answers are calculated? In both cases you want $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$ with $A\subset B$, so it's not clear why the calculations should be any different.

Comment: calculations for both parts:

Comment: 1. P (3rd card is K| 1st and 2nd are K) = 2/50

Comment: 2. P( 3 Kings| at least 2 Kinds) = 4C3 / ( 4C3 + (4C2 x 48C1))

Comment: Is the difference in wording of these questions is due to the fact that in question 1 we are certain that we are dealt 2 Kings whereas in question 2 we don't know - we might have 2 Kings or 3Kings and we want to know what are the chances we got 3 and not 2?

Comment: I don't understand. In the question you say that one answer was calculated using a conditional probability formula, whereas the other answer was calculated using Bayes' Theorem. How is that reflected in your comments above?

Comment: I made a mistake in the description of the problem. They are both calculated using conditional probability.

Comment: The difference is that you know what the first two cards are in one case but not in the other. A non-king can only appear in one place in the first problem, but in any of three places in the second.

Comment: @Stacy: But that was the substance of your question, no? Is there anything left that you'd like to have answered?

Comment: @amd Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @joriki  amd explained it perfectly.

Comment: @Stacy: You could write up the answer and accept it, so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.